# Media query in chrome: fail to combine "not print" with other rule

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, media-queries

Combining "not print" and a rule does not seem to work. If I combine "not print" it looks like the second part (max-width: 600px) gets ignored ..

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
@media not print and (max-width:600px) {
   html { background-color: red;}
}
</style>
<body>
test
</body>
</html>
```

This snippet does work?

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
@media (max-width:600px) {
   html { background-color: red;}
}
</style>
<body>
test
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you expecting the first example to produce a red background or white background in non-print media?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you not be better of using the following for general styles...

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  // styles go here
}
```

and then have print specific styles using the following...

```
@media print {
  // print specific styles go here...
}
```

I hope this helps...

Comment: Yep this is the only way to go. I thought it was a boolean operator. 

Most of the times !A and B is not equivalent to !(A and B).. but with this not operator it is.

Answer (score 0):

In CSS Level 3 media queries, `not` can only appear at the start of the media query (as you have it, and also requires a media type, which you have), and [negates the entire media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media#logical_operators).

So `not print and (max-width: 600px)` is interpreted as (pseudo) `not (print and (max-width: 600px))` which means it will match all non-print media as well as media greater than `600px` in width.  In other words, unless you are printing on small paper, the inner rules will be applied.

Hope this adds some explanation to the other answers.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you are looking for this:

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
@media not print, (max-width:600px) {
   html { background-color: red;}
}
</style>
<body>
test
</body>
</html>
```

This says to the browser, not print *and* max-width of 600px. Whereas before it was saying "not print and not max-width: 600px".

MDN has a good set of examples on how the [not operator works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries#Logical_operators).

Comment: This really says: not print OR max-width of 600px..


not X and Y is really not (X and Y) as the not operator really negates the WHOLE media query. I just learned on MDN.. 


screen and (max-width: 600px) is what i'm looking for..